# "While" loop in Scheme skips iteration

Tags: scheme

I have to learn the basics of Scheme to complete a project, but I'm having a little difficulty constructing the equivalent of a while loop. For instance, in the following code, I want to have the user input a character. If the character is an x, I want to break out of the loop. If it is any other character, the character will be displayed, and the loop proceeds with the next iteration.

```
(define getUserChar (lambda ()
(define ch)
  (let loop ()
    (display "Enter character: ")
    (set! ch (read-char))
    (if (not (char=? ch #\x))
       (begin
       (display choice)
       (loop)
 )))))
```

This technically does work, but it skips an iteration. For example:

```
Enter character: a
Enter character:
Enter character: s
```

I am not able to input a character during that second iteration. I can't seem to pinpoint the problem. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're actually reading *two* characters. The one you typed, plus the line break. I tried to preserve as much as possible from your original solution, and this is what I came up with:

```
(define getUserChar
  (lambda ()
    (define ch #\0)
    (let loop ()
      (display "Enter character: ")
      (set! ch (string-ref (read-line) 0))
      (if (not (char=? ch #\x))
          (begin
            (display ch)
            (newline)
            (loop))))))
```

IMHO a more idiomatic solution doesn't require a mutation operation, I prefer this one:

```
(define (getUserChar)
  (let loop ((ch #\0))
    (unless (char=? ch #\x)
      (display "Enter character: ")
      (let ((ch (string-ref (read-line) 0)))
        (display ch)
        (newline)
        (loop ch)))))
```

Comment: I always forget about that detail when reading input. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @Robbeh my pleasure! I updated my answer with a more idiomatic solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the fact that you are entering two characters in the very first iteration of the loop, namely `"a\n"` (`"a~n"`) and that makes the second iteration just take the `#\NewLine` you entered together with the `#\a` as the character.

If you want to take a whole line at a time you [get-line](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_706) (R6RS) or `read-line` (R7RS) instead or look at [buffer-mode](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_576) (R6RS) and slurp the chars before starting the new iteration to continue using chars.